# Unity www "aborted" error

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have the following error

when I try to download a mp4 file with unity www class it failed with only "aborted" error message in www.error

its a weird error, it only appear on some devices, I have tried it on galaxy note 5 and works well, and when some one have tried it on a galaxy s7, he get that error

any one mybe know what is hapening?

Thanks for your help guys.

the code to download the video

```
private IEnumerator DownloadVideo()
{
    showDownloadProgress = true;
    downloadProgress.gameObject.SetActive(true);

    videoURL = MainPlayerCTRL.mediaURL;
    Uri uri = new Uri(videoURL);
    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
    string localFilePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/"+ filename;
    bool tryVideoDownload = true;

    if (!File.Exists(localFilePath))
    {
        while (tryVideoDownload)
        {
            downloadProgressText.text = "Downloading";
            showDownloadProgress = true;
            downloadProgress.gameObject.SetActive(true);

            www = new WWW(videoURL);
            yield return www;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
            {
                byte[] bytes = www.bytes;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Create);
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                downloadProgressText.text = "Download done!";
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
                tryVideoDownload = false;
            }//Video downloaded
            else
            {
                showDownloadProgress = false;
                downloadProgress.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                downloadProgressText.text = "Download ERROR \n ";
                downloadProgressText.text += www.error;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
                downloadProgressText.text = "Attempting to download again";
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
                tryVideoDownload = true;
            }
        }

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }

}
```

Comment: How large is the video? Also, what is the device model it is failing on? This is very likely a memory issue. Not sure yet without knowing all these info.

Comment: the video size is 250 mb, you think it can be temporal memory issue? the smartphone have more than 2gb in the internal and external storage.

Comment: `Internal and External storage` != `Ram`. People confuse this two. I once ran into this problem once and wrote a solution for it. Will put answer if I find it on my computer.

Comment: yes I know the difference, I mean if you thing if the problem can be that (ram) or a internal/external storage problem

Comment: Oh ok. Didn't get that. It's very likely it is the ram. Check back to this question in about an hour.

Comment: Thakns, I will be alert :)

Comment: I just realized that WWW is throwing the error not FileStream. So this may not be a memory issue. Try the solution in my answer and let me know if the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I suspected was low memory that usually happen when copying large file with `FileStream` but you mentioned that you got "aborted" error from `www.error`. The culprit is likely `WWW` and the first thing to do is to use [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html). I replaced `WWW` in your function with [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html).

You will need to include `using UnityEngine.Networking;` at the top in order to use this. Another thing is that `yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();` is supposed to be inside the while loop not outside it and using `yield return null;` is better.

```
private IEnumerator DownloadVideo()
{
    showDownloadProgress = true;
    downloadProgress.gameObject.SetActive(true);

    videoURL = MainPlayerCTRL.mediaURL;
    Uri uri = new Uri(videoURL);
    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
    string localFilePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + filename;
    bool tryVideoDownload = true;

    if (!File.Exists(localFilePath))
    {
        while (tryVideoDownload)
        {
            downloadProgressText.text = "Downloading";
            showDownloadProgress = true;
            downloadProgress.gameObject.SetActive(true);

            UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(videoURL);
            yield return www.Send();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
            {
                byte[] bytes = www.downloadHandler.data;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Create);
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                downloadProgressText.text = "Download done!";
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
                tryVideoDownload = false;
            }//Video downloaded
            else
            {
                showDownloadProgress = false;
                downloadProgress.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                downloadProgressText.text = "Download ERROR \n ";
                downloadProgressText.text += www.error;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
                downloadProgressText.text = "Attempting to download again";
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
                tryVideoDownload = true;
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I will try in both devices and will let you know how it works.

Comment: Ok. Will be waiting

Comment: hi, it woks well in galaxy note 5 device, like when i use www, but in the s7 device the app crashes when the app starts (the download video scene)

Comment: I thing maybe the problem can be the device?

Comment: It's too early to pin in on the device right now. Can you comment every code other than `UnityWebRequest`? I will use this to determine what to do next.

Comment: commented, in the galaxy note 5 works well, in the s7 device the app crash when the scene is loaded

Comment: Use Android Studio to view logcat. There should be a crash log displayed it crashes. Post that here.

Comment: SOLVED! the problem was a couple of big textures loaded in tne last loaded scene, that have caused a memory leak, i just have modified my code to load the textures in demand and not all at the same time, thanks!